# how can i find the approximate value of this?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, approximation

Using the total differential, find the approximate value of:

$$8.02^{(\frac{1}{3})}*\sqrt{(3.96)^2+(3.03)^2}$$

how can I find the approximate value of this using partial derivatives, explain, please

Comment: Your equation can be written in the form $(x+\Delta x)^{1/3}\sqrt{(y+\Delta y)^2+(x+\Delta z)^2}$. Then you can approximate this using Taylor expansions around the point $(x,y,z)$, for example.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assume $$f(x,y,z)=(x)^{\frac{1}{3}}*\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$$
$$x=8;y=4;z=3$$you get:
$$f(x,y,z)=10$$use this:
$$df=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}dx+\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}dy+\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}}dz$$

$$dx=0.02;dy=-0.04;dz=0.03$$

find the partials and solve, then find $f(8,4,3)+df$, you must get around$(9.98)$

Answer (score 1):

Define $u{(x,y,z)} = x^{1/3}\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$

Assume $x=8$, $y=4$, $z=3$

$dx = 0.02$, $dy = -0.04$ and $dz = +0.03$

Then find

> $u(8,4,3)$

and

> $du = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial }dy+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}dz$

The approximate value will be

> $u(8,4,3)+du$